# NPE ответа сервера

Tags: java, android, retrofit, null

Было и раньше подобное предупреждение, но как то не особо придавал значение, так как проверка с toast’ом проходила и кол-во лайков показывает к примеру.

А проблема собственно в этой строке

```
for (WallItem item : response.body().response.getItems()) {
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   ‘java.util.List
>   com.vkproject.vm.vkproject.rest.model.response.BaseItemResponse.getItems()’
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.vkproject.vm.vkproject.ui.fragment.NewsFeedFragment$1.onResponse(NewsFeedFragment.java:61)

При наведении на `response.body()` подсвечивает мол Difference of response.body() my produce NPE, пробовал добавлять проверку до, мол:

```
if (response.body() != null) {

участок кода

}
```

Но увы мимо :(

Comment: у вас получается response.body().response == null

Comment: А в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: @LexHobbit не могу понять почему null, а можно сделать что то типо как в kotlin'e `?.` ?

Comment: @eugeneek вопрос собственно как избежать этого null'a. Но скорей всего уже начал понимать, что проблема кроется где то в получении данных.